# Display lowest price in configurable products instead of zero

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, configurable-product, price

I have been looking for a solution for days now.

How do you display the lowest price of simples in a configurable product instead of zero on price.phtml page?

I got this issue resolved by using bundle product option, instead of configurable.  With bundle products, I can set a base default price from simples attached.

Comment: Is this possible?  And also display the price range for the lowest to highest price of attributes? I have done this using `$_product->getMinPrice()` and `$_product->getMaxPrice()` in list.phtml.  But I can't reproduce it here. How could this be achieved?

Comment: `echo '<pre>';print_r($_product);echo '</pre>';` and see what is in the product object you have.

Comment: @TimHallman  Should I place the code in price.phtml?  Around what line?

Comment: I have been working on the code from this thread http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/51788/how-to-display-available-lowest-price-for-magento-configurable-products, suggested by @ChristopherRoach.  It works fine on "price.phtml". It displays the min price, but it breaks the code on other categories pages!

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you don't want to have price '0' on the configurable product. It should have a base price, and then additional options may cost more.

If your pricing model is made so that different options will always have a different price, you may want to look at [Simple Configurable Products](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/simple-configurable-products.html) - this extension will use the prices on the Simple products everywhere. It might be easier to manage for you than Magento's default implementation.

Comment: @vladfre Thank you for the reply. Ideally you are correct.  But majority of shopping carts, allow products to have a zero base price, because some product prices are based on their size attributes. Let say you have 1000s of picture frames with their own SKUs.  Picture Frame Style A (skuA), have sizes 2x3 costing 10.00 (skuA-01), 4x5 costing 25.00 (skuA-02) and 8x10 costing 40.00 (skuA-03).  If you place the Frame Style A 2x3 as your base, you MUST first in the product description state its size as 2x3 (you need that description so the shopper knows what size they have purchased).

Comment: if you are sold out and discontinued of size 2x3. The description stays their for ever.  Second if you run out of size 2x3 (simple product qty 0)? When you go to the product page you would no longer see the size 2x3, the shopper would see every other size in the cart.  The shopper would ask what this 25.00 is for. They don't understand cart logic wants to have a base price? All they want to know is how much each size cost. If a product is not in stock, it’s either grayed out marked out or just not there. And I could go on with problems that some shop owners will have with this logic!

Comment: I don’t want to give you a head ache talking about the problem you might have in the back-end! Now regarding **Simple Configurable Products**, I tried it and it freezes when re-indexing the “Product Prices" Index.  So that is not a good solution.  It is very crucial to have these types of products not tide into the base product and have them as their own skus, with their own information.

Comment: And finally it's really bad if shopper sees 0.00 for the price on the product page.